# Touchpad not working on Debian 9

Tags: debian, xorg, touchpad

I just installed Debian 9 on a Lenovo S130-14IGM but the touchpad doesn't work at all.
With Ubuntu there is no problem with it.

Here are the results from the two operating systems:

**Ubuntu**

```
# egrep -i 'syna|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="SYNA3388:00 06CB:8459 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA3388:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-4/i2c-SYNA3388:00/0018:06CB:8459.0001/input/input17

# apt list xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Listing...
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 amd64

# dpkg -l | grep -i syna
ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                    amd64        Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server

# xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3388:00 06CB:8459 Touchpad            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**Debian**

```
# egrep -i 'syna|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices
-

# apt list xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
En train de lister…
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/stable 1.9.0-1+b1 amd64


# dpkg -l | grep -i syna
ii  synaptic                              0.84.2                            amd64        Graphical package manager

# xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# egrep -i 'syna|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="SYNA3388:00 06CB:8459 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA3388:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-4/i2c-SYNA3388:00/0018:06CB:8459.0001/input/input17
```

Your touchpad is not connected to the system via internal PS/2 or USB wiring, but using the I2C bus. This is a fairly new development, and Debian 9's standard kernel might be too old to support such touchpads very well. You might try with a backport kernel.

[See here](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) for instructions in enabling the Debian Backports repository - basically, add this line to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

Then you should be able to install a backport kernel with:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t stretch-backports install linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 linux-image-amd64
```

After a reboot, you might then have better luck with your touchpad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I don't manage to get backports to work. I've added the `stretch-backports` line, updated and run the install. I encounter the following error : 
`E: The value ‘stretch-backports’ is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`
 
So I tried with testing repo and now the mouse work fine ! I would like to understand the problem with backports if have an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I've done it that why I said : "added the line, updated and run the install". But I still have the error. When running `apt-get update` strech-backports is correctly downloaded but when trying to install a package I have the error.

Comment: @GAD3R, yes of course. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Debian wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad):

**Debian 9 "Stretch"**

In most cases, make sure you have xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse installed, and not the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package.

Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev for more info on evdev.

Try `apt remove`ing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and installing the above packages.