# debian 10 touchpad does not work

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

I tried the methods on this page 
https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad but it does not work. 
Actually I also tried methods here
[Touchpad not working on Debian 9](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509766/touchpad-not-working-on-debian-9)
by adding

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

and

```
apt-get -t stretch-backports install linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 linux-image-amd64
```

does not get anything

My computer is Lenovo L580, currently my source is

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ stable  main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with kernel parameter

```
psmouse.elantech_smbus=0
```

See [Kernel Boot Parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) (Ubuntu Wiki) how to add the parameter temporarily for testing and permanently.

It would only make sense to use `stretch-backports` if you were running Debian 9 `stretch` (which you are not). Backports are packages for the next release ("testing") compiled to work with the current "stable" release.

Related:

- [#943370 linux-image-amd64: Elantech touchpad not working (elan_i2c)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943370) (Debian Bug report)
- [1825699 Touchpad not working on Lenovo ThinkPad L580 after upgrade to 19.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1825699) (Ubuntu Bug report)